# Find out next character for a given sequence of characters (logic test style) (Java)

Tags: java, logic, sequence

I recently took a logic quiz/test with questions like: What is the next character for the sequence: `a,c,b,d,c`? Although not complicated I only managed to complete like half of them in the given time limit.

So I would like for my next try to use: either a script built by me or a tool from the Internet.

Do you have any ideas how to approach this using java? Are there any classes that I could use or have to build from scratch? I found a tutorial on Java Regex Pattern & Matcher but I'm pretty sure it's not what I am looking for.

Note: It's always a-z chars & usually sets of 6 (+/-1)

Comment: I'd be interested to see the answer to this one because even though it may not seem that complicated, it would involve some form of artificial intelligence so I'd think you'd find that the code may end up quite large and complex unfortunately. Did you have any ideas?

Comment: You have to be kidding... I'm not going to read a book for this :). I will search for a pdf though, may there's some insight

Comment: Unfortunately, I am not kidding. Do you have the answer for the example in your question, and if so would you mid telling me how you worked it out? I have a feeling it could be "f" but I'm not sure... You see, to even start to imagine what the program would have to do, we instinctively look for a central character to which others and related to, and then find out the relationship. I don't even want to think about the code that would be involved in the initial process! May I ask, is this a project you've set yourself or something?

Comment: ..my bad, Andy. I did some googling, found some articles, referencing the book you mentioned.. so again.. my bad. And yes its a personal project

Answer (score 0):

What is the legal alphabet for the sequence?  Is it always a-z?  If so, then predicting the sequence isn't that difficult.  You could map the letters to 1-26 for a reasonable 'guesstimator'.

In this example:

1, 3, 2, 4, 3...

+2, -1, +2, -1...

You really need to qualify the question to determine how much modeling is required to solve the problem.

Comment: Hy. It's always a-z chars. I also thought of converting the chars to int... perhaps implements some specific sequences to test for: like Fibonacci... Oh. And they usually come in sets of 6 (+/-1).

Answer (score 0):

**The Simple Problem**

In your case, it appears you are picking the nth and n+2th letters, in turn (modulo the alphabet length) to continually generate the next letters in a sequence... The sequence might be staggered a little by some constant as well... But in either case, the exact solution should  be precisely decoded by a human and implemented in any language.

However, other comments on your question identify that this problem hints at a full blown, much more interesting problem  which is not easily solved by a human - but rather which requires hueristics.  This prediction problem is relevant to bioinformaticians and artificial intelligence engineers, wherein we want to predict the next letter or word (I.e. From a text stream or Amino acid sequence ) in a string given the preceding word/letter sequence...

**The FULL blown Problem**

This is a classic problem in artificial intelligence which requires machine learning .

The particular type of problem would take, as input :

the preceding sequence.

And output :

A single, next character in the sequence.

There is an AminoAcid predictor algorithm on github , which we've designed to deal with thus problem using machine learning, that runs in Clojure (see the jayunit100/Rudolf project) , if you are interested in a full blown approach to solving thus problem over a 22 amino acid alphabet.